# Not able to use Norwegian characters in url with Codeigniter 1.7

Tags: codeigniter

A part of link it has æ.

> http://localhost/myproject/index.php/welcome/pages/52/Velvære/161

When I click the link it shows the following error.

> The URI you submitted has disallowed
>   characters.

I have changed config file as follows but it still shows the same error.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\- æ ø å Æ Ø Å';
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That character is not an ASCII character, therefore it is not URL-safe. You should URL encode that segment, and then URL decode it on the server-side.